# Traversing a structure in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following structure:

```
Array
(
    [signupbasic] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Enter your first name or username
                    [email] => Enter your email address
                    [password] => Enter your password
                    [phone] => Enter your mobile number
                    [message1] => A text will be send to your phone - reply to validate
                    [gender] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Gender
                            [values] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Female] => 1
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Male] => 2
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [birthday] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Date of birth
                            [values] => date
                        )

                    [message2] => By clicking on "Continue" below you agree to Terms of Service and Privacy Policy
                )

        )

)
```

As you can see Gender & Birthday are arrays of different sizes. I am not getting how can I traverse the above structure due to the varying size of Gender and Birthday.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What code have you used to decode the `JSON`? Because PHP has a build-in function called `json_decode` since version 5.2. Have a look: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Hi Kevin.I have ued json_decode.My problem is "gender" and "birthday" are arrays of different dimensions so i am trying to find out how to parse it

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you're saying.. What **is** your problem? Why can't you traverse the object?

Comment: Hi Kevin.I want a generalized code for traversing the above json irrespective of the dimension of array. .If you observe in the above code "gender" and "birthdat" are of different dimensions. .Can you please provide sample code for how will you traver the above json in PHP

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just access those values separately? Just like you've **probably** done with `name`, `email` and `password`.

Let `$o` be the JSON and then do something along the lines of this:

```
$data = &$o['signupbasic'][0];

$genderObj   = $data['gender'];
$birthdayObj = $data['birthday'];
```

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish, could you post some PHP code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I got what you meant, but would it be something like this ?

```
foreach($json['signupbasic'][0]['gender']['values'] as $genderValue) {
  foreach($genderValue as $genderKey => $genderSubVal) {
    echo $genderKey." ".$genderSubVal."\n\r";
  }
}

foreach($json['signupbasic'][0]['birthday'] as $bdKey => $bdValue) {
  echo $bdKey." ".$bdValue."\n\r";
}
```

Assuming $json is the return value of your json_decode call.

Answer (score 0):

For php to understanding json, it needs to be in a special format

```
{
    "property1": "value1",
    "property2": "value2",
    "property3": "value3",
    "property4": "value4"
}
```

see a better explenation on php.net [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function